# Container components are bad? Should use store.getState and store.dispatch directly instead?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In react, the way it figures out if it needs to re-render-dom is by testing references of objects/functions.

So on every update all the JS is calculated. Meaning container elements return two brand new objects each time, one for `maptDispatchToProps` and one for `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter))
    }
  }
}
```

In above code we see a new object every time containing `active` key and then a new object *containing a new function* to `onClick`. The references to these 3 are brand new on each js-cycle. React will compare these references and then it will re-calc the js in the component. But I thought with redux there was no need for testing `shouldComponentUpdate`, how can this be when all these 3 references changed? Especiall the `onClick`, that will cause react to `removeEventListener` then add the `onClick` back again with `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how "shallow equality" works.  Both React's `PureRenderMixin` and React Redux's `connect` function use "shallow equality" to determine if something has actually changed.  That means that the *top-level values* of two objects are compared to see if each pair of values is `===` equal, rather than comparing if the *objects themselves* are the same.  So, if I have:

```
var a = {q : 42};
var b = {a : a};
var c = {a : a};
```

Then B and C are distinctly different objects, but shallow-equal, because for both of them, the "a" field points to the same object.

Also, in the case of React Redux's `connect()` function, it primarily checks the return value of `mapStateToProps` to see if the wrapped component needs to update.

Comment: Thanks mark, what about the function `onClick` returned by `mapDipsatchToProps`, an equality check on that would surely return different no? I was confused because from the reducers, if nothing changed I return `undefined` but i got an error in console which told me not to do that, and instead to return the original `state` param which would mean same reference.

Comment: The `connect()` function checks the declaration of your `mapDispatchToProps` to see if it takes one or two arguments.  If it only takes one arg, then your `mapDispatch` doesn't rely on props passed to the component, so it will only ever be run once.  If your `mapDispatch` takes _two_ args, it depends on incoming props, so it will be re-run when the parent component re-renders.  In that case, you would probably have created a new set of functions, and it would cause the real component to re-render. You could restructure your `mapDispatch` and component to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks @mark I have to think about this more. Thanks very much.